# Change of arrow head in $\xymatrix{}

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

Let us consider the following example :

```
$A\xrightarrow{\quad } B$
```

This gives

[image]

But in the following way we can change arrow head

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemarrow,amsmath}
 \let\rightarrow\chemarrow
 \begin{document}
  $A\xrightarrow{\quad } B$
  \end{document}
```

and this gives

[image]

Now,

```
    \documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[all]{xy}
 \begin{document}
  $$\xymatrix{A \ar[r]& B}$$
 \end{document}
```

This gives
[image]

But I want using \xymatrix :

[image]

I have tried with the following way but it is not working

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{chemarrow}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
 \let\xymatrix\chemarrow
\begin{document}
 $$\xymatrix{A \ar[r]& B}$$
 \end{document}
```

Any one can help me to do so.

Comment: @percusse still not a question, ergo still abusive.

Comment: @JanDvorak abusive is a stretch, it's just not good. And ergo makes me itch (no offense)

Comment: @ideal: Welcome to the site! Something seems to have gone wrong with your post: there doesn't seem to be a question. Maybe you pressed "Post" prematurely? Could you edit your post to explain what you're asking?

Comment: In addition, please post full minimal examples also in the case os `\xymarix`. That makes it a lot easier to for others to help.

Comment: You can't (easily) change the arrowhead in Xy-pic. Why don't you switch to `tikz-cd`?

Comment: Why did the comments disappear here?